# Invalid Column name for a Temporary table column in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure inside of which a temporary table is created:

I get an error that says:

> Invalid column name 'ValFromUser'.

Why is that? Why do I get this error only for ValFromuser but no other column?How I may get rid of this?

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[OutputProcedure]

--declarations here 
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.##Temp2') Is null
Begin
create table ##Temp2
(
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromUser nvarchar(30),
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null
);

select * 
from dbo.ResultsStored
join (
    select 
        Rownumber,
        (SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Perc 
    from ##Temp2 
    GROUP BY 
        Rownumber, ValFromUser
) t -- Invalid column Name ValFromUser error here
    on dbo.ResultsStored.RowId = t.Rownumber
    and dbo.ResultsStored.HashedKey = HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
end

End



Insert into dbo.ResultsStored( searchSerial,FinalSearchSeral, StringSearched, RowId,PercentMatch, HashedKey) 
select @searchNumber, @searchNumber, dbo.encrypt(@StringConcat), RowNumber, (SUM(Percentage)/@cnt) as Percentage , HASHBYTES('MD5', @StringConcat)
FROM ##Temp2 GROUP BY RowNumber, ValFromUser --Here

end
```

Comment: You have a number of syntax errors in your stored procedure.

Comment: You have a comma at the end of the last line of the temporary table definition.  This code would produce an error, but that would not be the error.  You need to put in the code you are actually using -- or a simplified version that exhibits the same error.

Answer (score 1):

At the last line of create table statement. Remove comma(,) and reply your result again.

```
create table ##Temp2
(
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromUser nvarchar(30),
--ColumnName nvarchar(30),
--ValFromFunc decimal(18, 4),
--FuncWeight decimal(18, 4),
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null
);
```

Answer (score 1):

1: Try a selecting ##Temp2 table and check whether you are getting the ValFromUser column displayed. If not drop the ##Temp table and execute your  above statements again.

2: Remove the Comma (,) after the last column from "**Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null,**" The

```
create table ##Temp2
(
Rownumber int not null,
ValFromUser nvarchar(30),
--ColumnName nvarchar(30),
--ValFromFunc decimal(18, 4),
--FuncWeight decimal(18, 4),
Percentage decimal(18, 4) not null
);
```

3: Include ValFromUser Column in the select statement

```
Select Rownumber, ValFromUser, (SUM(Percentage) / @cnt) as Perc 
FROM ##Temp2 
GROUP BY Rownumber, ValFromUser
```

Try the above steps and let me know whether it solves your problem or not ?

Comment: I can not unnecessarily add it in select as I am doing insert using select at that statement .

Comment: SELECT * FROM ##Temp2, whether the select statement shows ValFromUser column ?

Comment: It does appear in select * statement. However, I do not get it in suggestion while typing to use it in group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this. I had a temp table in my sp that was getting the error:

```
Invalid column name <column name>
```

I was only running the stored procedure when I am encountering this. However, the stored procedure is run on a query window where I was also testing the code (for another bug) where I declared the temp table but without the the erroring fields specified (for brevity).

When I renamed the sp's temp table, the problem disappeared. So, I am guessing that the sp is calling this temp table instead of the one that I specified in the sp.